# Automatic time input on form Javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime

Hi everyone I'm new to coding and when creating a form that has current date /  time input I set around looking to find a way to have this area of the form automatic.

I found this piece of javascript on here and it's working great for the date input

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function SetDate()
 {
 var date = new Date();

 var day = date.getDate();
 var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
 var year = date.getFullYear();

 if (month < 10) month = "0" + month;
 if (day < 10) day = "0" + day;

 var today = year + "-" + month + "-" + day;


 document.getElementById('date').value = today;
 }
 </script>

 <body onload="SetDate();">
```

I have sat for countless hours trying to re write this code to automatically input the time but not having much luck, I'm not just looking for someone to type it for me and it to work as I'm genuinely trying to learn so if anyone can point me out where im going wrong here is the piece of code I'm trying to make work for hours / minutes based on the other persons code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function SetDate()
{
var date = new Date();

var hours = date.getHours();
var mins = date.getMinutes();


if (hours < 10) hours = "0" + hours;
if (mins < 10) mins = "0" + mins;

var time = hours + "-" + mins + "-" + day;


document.getElementById('date').value = time;
}
</script>

<body onload="SetDate();">
```

I have also just noticed that when I have this code on the page the working automatic Date **stops** working

Any help will be appreciated whole heartedly

Comment: Explain how it isn't working, what does it do? What errors are you getting in the browser console?

Comment: Totally forgot about the console thing etc on Chrome I've been doing this blind as such just mucking about untill it works

Comment: "The specified value "18-48" does not conform to the required format, "yyyy-MM-dd"."

Comment: You never define day anywhere.. also you have some validation set up on your form so you have to  either change the validation criteria or change the string you input into the form

Comment: I only need the day in the top one don't I?  also I cant find anywhere to edit the validation criteria could you help me with the string input

Answer (score 0):

First, an HTML document can only have a single `<body>` tag. Second, both your scripts get an element with a `#date` id. If they both write to the same element, one will overwrite the other's result. Third, you've not defined a `day` variable in your time function.

Comment: Okay thanks for this, and as the #date is the same code is there a way for me to only need to write this once?

Comment: Yes, write both your date and time logic in the one function.

Answer (score 0):

Lazy way to solve the problem:

```
document.getElementById('date').value = Date().toString();
```

Seriously: 
declare `var day = date.getDate()`

Try to press F12 in chrome or firefox to open the developer tools, then click in `console` tab to see what are the errors. Machine debug much better then human